# Getting a new array with just the elements that contain certain value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I’ve got the following array:

```
$myArray
: array = 
  0: array = 
    0: string = 2012
    1: string = 1
    2: string = JOHN
  1: array = 
    0: string = 2012
    1: string = 2
    2: string = JOHN
  2: array = 
    0: string = 2012
    1: string = 3
    2: string = MARK
```

I’ve also have the variable $name.
Let’s say that this time $name equals JOHN

What do I have to do to have a new array with just the elements that contain JOHN like this:

```
$myArray
: array = 
  0: array = 
    0: string = 2012
    1: string = 1
    2: string = JOHN
  1: array = 
    0: string = 2012
    1: string = 2
    2: string = JOHN
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: Well have you at least tried doing it the manual way of looping through all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function search ($arr, $name){
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        if ($v[2] == $name)
            $result[] = $v;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This function returns an array containing only the values you want.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a custom callback; in this case using a closure:

```
// $name is the variable containing 'JOHN'
$array2 = array_filter($array1, function($val) use ($name) {
   return $val[2] === $name;
});
```